# Code refactoring by injecting a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, iterator, code-injection

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and the Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 gem. I would like to *refactoring the following code to one line*:

```
args ||= {}

@i_vars = {}
args.each { |key, opts| @i_vars[key] = IVar.new(key, opts, args.keys) }
```

I thought to use the [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method something like this:

```
args ||= {}

@ivars = args.inject({}) { |result, (key, opts)| result.merge( @i_vars[key] = IVar.new(key, opts, args.keys) ) }
```

However, the latter code returns different results when setting the `@i_vars` variable. I tried also others implementations of the `inject` method but without success.

There is a way to refactoring the code? or, maybe, should I use some other method or some RoR feature (unknown to me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should write in the `inject` block:

```
result.update(key => IVar.new(key, opts, args.keys)
```

But no need to use `inject` or `each_with_object` to build a hash, we have `Hash[pairs]`:

```
@i_vars = Hash[(args || {}).map { |k, opts| [k, IVar.new(k, opts, (args || {}).keys)] }
```

However, I wouldn't obsess with one-liners, I'd write an equivalent but more clear code:

```
hargs = args || {}
@i_vars = Hash[hargs.map do |key, opts| 
  [key, IVar.new(key, opts, hargs.keys)]
end]
```

Comment: Thank you, but why should I prefer the `Hash` method instead of the useful `each_with_object`?

Comment: because it's shorter and is designed for that very task: convert pairs to hashes. `each_with_object` is indeed useful, but I wouldn't use it when there is a more fitting abstraction. `Hash[pairs]` vs `pairs.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), acc| acc[key] = value }`.

Comment: And for what purpose are designed `inject` and `each_with_object` methods?

Comment: @Backo: Both are generic folding methods and are extremely useful. In fact Hash[...] might be perfectly written with any of them. The key is to use the right abstraction for the task. Note that you can do all sorts of things with `inject` (`map`, `select`, ...), but that's not a reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [each_with_object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
@i_vars = args.each_with_object({}) do |key,opts,result|
  result[key] = IVar.new(key, opts, args.keys)
end
```